# How to get logstreams from EMR steps to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr

We use Airflow to orchestrate aws ETL jobs. Some of these jobs start an EMR cluster and add EMR steps to that cluster. Airflow pulls logs from Cloudwatch. Logs created during an EMR step is not directly available in CloudWatch, but are only found in hidden in the cluster logs. If an EMR step fails, the logs to identify the error is therefore not readily available. We would like logs created from EMR steps to be displayed in CloudWatch. We have tried the installing the CloudWatch agent, but that does not seem to work. How can we get logstreams from EMR steps to CloudWatch?